# Jumping out of upside down helicopter, will turbine wind cancel me out like a bloey joey?

Tags: gravity, momentum, drag

How long would it take to cancel the speed you're going when you leap out of your helicopter, after it does do an aerial flip and is flying straight downward?

I used to say, "college felt like flying an upside down helicopter", because of the complexity and drinking, and I wonder what the metaphor would be like, to step out of an upside down helicopter, and just cancel momentum, to walk on to a skyscraper balcony, as if casually strolling.  Maybe I should ask this in 3d animators or James Bond enthusiasts.

Comment: If the helicopter actually was _flying_ up-side down, If it actually was possible for the pilot to control it, and for the engine to keep running, and for the rotor to generate that much "negative" thrust, then wouldn't you fall in to the rotor when you stepped out?

Comment: It would probably need a lot of upward momentum, maybe stall out and flip, then throttle it, giving an air boost.  *James Bond music*